# HelloWorld.dll SharePoint Feature Activation Error

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am now able to use gacutil.exe and sn.exe to get my HelloWorld.dll into GAC, and get it uploaded to SharePoint.
I can see it in the Features list.
However, when I try to activate it, i get:

```
Feature '79bc44ea-93f5-4886-8784-8f3fbd1dfa48' could not be installed because the loading of      event      receiver assembly "HelloWorld, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=b169cb5c722a4763" failed: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'HelloWorld\, Version 1.0.0.0\, Culture\=neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=b169cb5c722a4763' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047) 
File name: 'HelloWorld\, Version 1.0.0.0\, Culture\=neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=b169cb5c722a4763' 
at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(Assembly& assembly, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean     raiseResolveEvent) 
at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
```

This is a newbie Feature, and it has an event handler, my feature.xml file:

```
<Feature
Id="79bc44ea-93f5-4886-8784-8f3fbd1dfa48"
Title="Hello World Feature"
Description="This is my first custom Featuree"
Scope="Web"
Hidden="False"
ImageUrl="menuprofile.gif"
ReceiverAssembly="HelloWorld, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b169cb5c722a4763"
ReceiverClass="HelloWorld.FeatureReceiver"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

<ElementManifests>
<ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>
</ElementManifests>

</Feature>
```

My elements.xml file:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <CustomAction
 Id="SiteActionsToolbar"
 GroupId="SiteActions"
 Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
 Sequence="100"
 Title="Hello World"
 Description="A custom menu item added using a Feature"
 ImageUrl="_layouts/images/menuprofile.gif">
 <UrlAction Url="http://msdn.microsoft.com"/>
</CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

when i run sn.exe, the dll is valid, and it is in the GAC. Due to the event handler, i do have a .cs file, which I assume is in the dll?
Does it matter if I made up the Feature "Id", I just copied a number from the code example I am using.?
Any other general areas for me to look into?

Here's the receiver class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace HelloWorld
{
public class FeatureReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
    public override void       FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
    }
    public override void   FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
    }
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("...in HelloWorld.FeatureActiviated()...");
        SPWeb site = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
        site.Properties["OriginalTitle"] = site.Title;
        site.Properties.Update();
        site.Title = "Hello World";
        site.Update();
    }
    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb site = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
        site.Title= site.Properties["OriginalTitle"] = site.Title;
        site.Update();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the receiver class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Feature ID must be unique, that's true. And you can make it up yorself or use guidgen.exe (I have it at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\guidgen.exe)
2. You will probably do better if you download [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) for Visual Studio and add to project new item "Feature with Receiver" that will automatically provide a valid feature.xml and a valid class for feature receiver code.